# Issues with Redirection and HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, redirection

I have two URLs:

- `https://example.com/view?id=1001554` - Old URL
- `https://example.ca/search-item.html?psid=1001554` - New URL

As you can see the site changes from `.com` to `.ca` and on the new URL there is a HTML page inserted into the URL. As well the `?id` is changed to `?psid` as well.

I have looked at many examples but there is none that has just the page in the new URL. Could someone assist me in the `.htaccess` file and making this work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^view$ https://example.ca/search-item.html?psid=%1 [R=302,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the captured URL parameter value from the preceding *CondPattern*.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed that it works as intended.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html